# Laravel eloquent does not update JSON column : Array to string conversion

Tags: php, mysql, json, laravel, eloquent

I want to update a **JSON** column in my database but I get this error :

```
Array to string conversion
```

I have declared the column name as `array` in the model :

```
protected $casts = [
    'destinations' => 'array'
];
```

this is the code that I use :

```
$data[] = [
    'from' => $fromArray,
    'to' => $toArray
];

Flight::where('id', $id)->update(['destinations' => $data]);
```

What should I do ?

Comment: Try this : `$flight = Flight::find($id); $flight->destinations = $data; $flight->save();` see [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/15464)

Comment: @Maraboc post your answer please

Comment: I just realised the need to add a laravel version tag to a question. I need to do update on in my laravel project but I don't know which version this question is targeted.

Comment: In my case I had similar problem, and it appeared I had forgotten about the `setDestinationsAttribute()` mutator which was the real culprit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to this conversation on Github : [Make json attributes fillable if Model field is fillable](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/15464) Taylor Otwell recommande the use of `save` method :

> $model->options = ['foo' => 'bar'];
>
> $model->save();

So in you case you can do it like this :

```
$flight = Flight::find($id); 
$flight->destinations = $data; 
$flight->save();
```

Comment: Why is this an accepted answer, again? This has NOTHING to do with database JSON type column  and an appropriate `JSON_SET` method!

Answer (score 14):

You can access your json keys using the arrow so you can update your column like so:

```
Flight::where('id', $id)->update([
   'destinations->from' => $data['from'],
   'destinations->to'  => $data['to']
]);
```

> As @fubar mentioned you have to have [mysql
>   5.7](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html) in order to have my solution to work.

check the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#updating-json-columns)

Comment: This isn't supported by all databases. E.g, MySQL 5.7+.

Answer (score 8):

This code did the work for me.

```
$user = User::where('id', $request->user_id)
        ->first();

$array_data = ["json_key3"=>"value"];

$user->forceFill([
    'db_column->json_key1->json_key2' => $array_data
])->save();
```

Answer (score 3):

You're getting that error because you're trying to update your model using the Query Builder, which basically just creates raw SQL queries. It isn't aware of any data casting, etc defined within your model. You therefore have three choices:

1) Find your model, and run the update on your model instance.

```
$flight = Flight::findOrFail($id);
$flight->update(['destinations' => $data]);
```

2) Convert the data to a string before updating.

```
$data = json_encode($data);
Flight::where('id', $id)->update(['destinations' => $data]);
```

3) Use a database that supports JSON column queries, per @AmrAly's suggestion. Beware of this option, as not all databases support JSON columns.

Comment: I know it can be done using `json_encode` but I wanted to use the casting feature of eloquent . thanks for the answer