# How to update json column using elequent laravel

Tags: php, laravel

how to update json column using elequent laravel

**This is example column [details_json]**

```
[
{
    "hex": "#FBE4D3",
    "img": ["1.jpg", "2.jpg"],
    "sizecount": [
        ["M", "S", "L"],
        [21, 222, 221]
    ]
}, {
    "hex": "#141310",
    "img": ["3.jpg", "4.jpg"],
    "sizecount": [
        ["Z", "E", "K"],
        [11, 21, 22]
    ]
}
]
```

**How to update like this **

```
$model->update(['details_json->0->hex' => '#fff']);
```

Comment: check if this thread help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45361861/laravel-eloquent-does-not-update-json-column-array-to-string-conversion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    $detailJson  = 
{
    "hex": "#FBE4D3",
    "img": ["1.jpg", "2.jpg"],
    "sizecount": [
        ["M", "S", "L"],
        [21, 222, 221]
    ]
}, {
    "hex": "#141310",
    "img": ["3.jpg", "4.jpg"],
    "sizecount": [
        ["Z", "E", "K"],
        [11, 21, 22]
    ]
}
];

$detailJson = json_decode($detailJson, 1);

$detailJson[0]['hex'] = '#FBE4D2';

model->update(['details_json' => json_encode($detailJson)]);
```

Comment: the question was how to update like this: `$model->update(['details_json->0->hex' => '#fff']);
`